# Event study estimates between matching groups

Tags: r, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, matching, treatment-effect

I have a dataset with: ID, years, $Y$ (dependent variable), treatment, a matching-group variable and a control variable $X$.

I have created the matching-group variable using $X$, the idea is to compare only comparable treated and control individuals (the control group is individuals with a higher or just a bit smaller $X$ than treated individuals having possible controls).

Now, I want to do an event study to estimate the average treatment effect over the years of my treatment, but I want to make sure treated and controls are compared only within their respective matching groups.

At first, I used this three-way fixed effect model (using the fixest package on R)

[image]

However, it does not do exactly what I want, that is to say, comparing treated and control individuals only within their grouping match. Do you have any idea on how I could do that?